How to click throw objects using Physics 2D Raycaster?
In my 2D project I need to click throw object(Clickable Area) on Table. I processing clicks on objects with physics raycaster 2D with IPointerClickHandler event. How can I do that? Because it can process only first intersection.
I tried to set up Physics 2D Raycaster in camera, I thought there are ray length/distance parameter, but I didn't find any parameters like that.
Tried make two raycasters for specific layers to process "Table" layer and "UI" layer, but it steel process only UI(first on way) intersection.
Objects need to handle click


raycasters dont "do" anything they are more like parking sensors

@BugFinder So my solution is to write own raycaster?

I didnt say that.  Which raycaster are you using?

@BugFinder I'm temporary using physics 2d raycaster attached to main camera with event system on scene and IPointerClickHandler on any clickable object.
Now i'm just planning how game will handle click.
I said i will write own raycaster, i meant i will create script attached on main camera, that will "shoot" ray in mouse position on screen with set lenght and call methods of objects with specified tags.

tbh Im not ssure why you didnt find the parameters, as clearly https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html covers them

You can use RaycastAll:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html
It will return an array of all the intersected elements.

I will try, thanks
